# Store indexes of a Series into an array

Tags: python, numpy

My idea is to apply linear regression to draw a line on a time series dataset to approximate the direction it is evolving in (first I draw the line, then I calculate the slope and I see if my plot is increasing decreasing, or constant).
For that, I relied on this code

```
def estimate_coef(x, y):
# number of observations/points
n = np.size(x)

# mean of x and y vector
m_x = np.mean(x)
m_y = np.mean(y)

# calculating cross-deviation and deviation about x
SS_xy = np.sum(y*x) - n*m_y*m_x
SS_xx = np.sum(x*x) - n*m_x*m_x

# calculating regression coefficients
b_1 = SS_xy / SS_xx
b_0 = m_y - b_1*m_x

return (b_0, b_1)

def plot_regression_line(x, y, b):
# plotting the actual points as scatter plot
plt.scatter(x, y, color = "m",
           marker = "o", s = 30)

# predicted response vector
y_pred = b[0] + b[1]*x

# plotting the regression line
plt.plot(x, y_pred, color = "g")

# putting labels
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

# function to show plot
plt.show()
```

For that I need an X and Y array.
The data I extracted had an index in the format of a date "Y-M-D".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXNID.png)

As you may know for linear regression it does not make sense to have the "date" as index, hence I used the `A.reset_index()` to get numeric indexes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFkfF.png)

Now that I got my data I need to extract the indexes to put them in an array "X" and the data to be plotted in an array "Y".
Therefore my question would be how to extract these new indexes and put them in the array X.

Comment: Please do not use images to display code.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
x=[i + 1 for i in A.index] # to make data x starts with 1 instead of 0
y=A['lift']
```

And you apply your functions on those `x` and `y`

Comment: `x = A.index.values` works as well, however you would get a numpy array instead of an `IndexRange`

Comment: @SpaceBurger when I use x=A.index + 1 aand try to display x i get "RangeIndex(start=1, stop=87, step=1)". However, I am interested in having an array.  Would both work if I intend to plot the "y" values? Also, would you consider this method appropriate for plotting the linear regression line according to my defined function in the beginning?

Comment: @Spearitch502 Please take a look at the new edits of my answer

Comment: @Spearitch502 Yes it does (at least in python 3.6.13, I don't know for other versions). You can write `plt.plot(A.index, A.lift)` and it should add the lines on your figure. However `plt.plot(A.index.values, A.lift.values)` has the advantage of being easier to debug as you just have to copy the X or Y statements to see what you get.